# Which Schema.org property should I use for related articles, quizzes, stories?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, schema.org, microdata

So there is a quiz & stories website, and on the right or bottom side of the screen (while you taking a quiz or read a story) there should be some lists of SIMILAR items, so the user can jump around at any time.

Examples, for story reader section (similar for quiz taker):

- recent stories AND/OR
- stories from same author AND/OR
- stories of same category AND/OR
- top rated stories of last week and so on

  - What schema.org should I use for this lists? I was thinking about `ItemList`. I would like to be as much SEO friendly as possible. 
    Please tell me your opinion about the below `ItemList`. Or if you think I should be using some else Microdata, please share it.
  - Is it fine to use the HTML5 element `article` for items of this list, or should I use something else, like a simple `div`?

```html
<aside id="rightSideBarAside" role="complementary" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">

<article class="storyArticle1" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
 <h2 itemprop="name">Name1</h2>
 <a href="" itemprop="url">address1</a>
</article>

<article class="storyArticle2" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
 <h2 itemprop="name">Name2</h2>
 <a href="" itemprop="url">address2</a>
</article>

</aside>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example misses the [`ItemList` type](http://schema.org/ItemList).

You could add it to the `aside` element, e.g.:

```html
<aside itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">

  <article itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  </article>

  <article itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  </article>

</aside>
```

Using the `article` element for each related story seems to be appropriate, especially if you provide content like a description/teaser, the author name etc. However, if you only provide the title and the link, you could as well use an `ul` element (without any headings), e.g.:

```
<aside>

  <ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">

    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
      <a href="…" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">…</span></a>
    </li>

    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
      <a href="…" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">…</span></a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</aside>
```

Schema.org’s [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) type does not provide a property for referencing related `Article` items. But the [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) type has the property [`relatedLink`](http://schema.org/relatedLink).

So you could use the `WebPage` type for each page, and reference related pages with the `relatedLink` property. And each `WebPage` has, as [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity), an `Article` item.

Comment: Thank you for answer and typo report. Added itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList"